# Creating a L shaped pattern with nested loops

Tags: c++, c++11, computer-science

For my intro C++ class, I am asked to create a L shaped pattern with little L's created inside of them using nested for loops. The size(width and height) is determined by a user input 'n'. I have the code, but I have NO idea how my professor came up with the code, and I really want to understand how he got to the code.

Example of running code:
input > 7

```
#o#o#o#
#o#o#oo
#o#o###
#o#oooo
#o#####
#oooooo
#######
```

Here is the code for accomplishing the task:

```
for (int r = n; r >= 1; r--) {
    for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {
        int x = r;
        if (c <= r)
            x = c;
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            cout << "o";
        else
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Even after an entire two days thinking about this, I don't understand what's going on in the inner forloop, the one that controls the columns. Please help me understand.

Comment: Turn off your computer. Get a pencil and some sheets of grid-lined paper. Then execute the program by hand, on paper, noting the values of each variable as you execute the loop and replicating output on paper. Then you will see.

Comment: Please learn [how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I did go through it fully on paper :/. However, the pattern just isn't clicking for me. 
The line: 

 int x = r;
        if (c <= r)
            x = c;
I don't understand whats going on here and why. I know the following lines after this is alternating o and # and but is going on before that in the line posted in this comment?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear. The second loop draws lines. In each line with number r it alternates # and o till reaches r-th column counting from right side, then repeats the last drawn symbol till the line end.

Comment: Ok I understood that it is alternating # and o because it does it on every even number "c". 
However, what is going on before that in the second loop? 
 int x = r;
        if (c <= r)
            x = c;
I can't figure out the point of this part.